# Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with time

Tags: nhibernate, time, types

I am using time datatype for a column in a table in sql server.I am working in a WPF project where we are using nhibernate in service layer for all database operations. Generated domain class,dto classes using entity developer. The time column was changed to timespan data type in the domain as well as dto classes. While saving the data into the table from I am getting an error "Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with time". Did anybody face similar issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
I had to change something in the mapping
.CustomType("TimeSpan") with .CustomType("TimeAsTimeSpan")